# How to delay calling of javascript function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-events

I'm new to JavaScript.

I would like to call JavaScript / jQuery function after the page load in aspx page.

I tried using  `<form onload="function()">` and `window.load = function(){}`, but the JavaScript is still trigger before some of the content fully loaded.

Is it possible to call during `Page_PreRender` in aspx page and not in code behind, so that I can delay the JavaScript function ?

I tried `setTimeout("function()",5000)` to solve the problem.

However `setTimeout()` seem like is not compatible with some browser, e.g: caused looping in Google Chrome.

Comment: Does `$(function(){})` not work for you?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

`setTimeout` is compatible with all browsers since 1996. You should avoid the evaluation of "functionName()" and instead do:

```
setTimeout(functionName,5000)
```

**UPDATE:** If you initially expect a variable passed to the function and none when in the timeout, you need to do this instead:

```
setTimeout(function() { functionName() },5000)
```

However you are calling the `onload` incorrectly, so you need to do either this:

```
window.addEventListener("load",function() {
  // your stuff
}
```

or the simpler

```
window.onload=function() {
  // your stuff
}
```

or, since you are using [jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/ready/#ready-handler), this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // your stuff
});
```

or just this:

```
$(function() {
    // your stuff
});
```

Answer (score 5):

If you want to be 100% sure that it's when the page ACTUALLY loads, use:

```
$(window).load(function(){
   //After EVERYTHING loads, including images.
})
```

The other's solution, `onload` works, but it loads once the DOM is ready, but not when the window is actually finished loading.

Answer (score 3):

If you're going to be using jQuery then it's preferable to attach an event to the document ready event using one of the following:

```
$(document).ready(callback);
```

or

```
$(document).ready(function () { /* do stuff */ });
```

or

```
$(callback);
```

or

```
$(function () { /* do stuff */ });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 

   //Code goes here

});
```

or old style

```
<body onload="myFunction()">
```

Comment: we do not do Old Style any more - please.

Comment: Okay, okay, I used it once when nothing else worked (IE6 + lot of scripts, long ago). And I don't like it too.

Comment: Old Style! kill it! burn it with a bat! smash it with fire! XP

Answer (score 0):

Would be best to use a framework like [jQuery](http://jquery.com/).
In jQuery you can define a function like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

});
```

This way it will be called when the DOM is fully loaded.

A full documentation of the ready() function can be found [here](http://api.jquery.com/ready/).