# Execute JS function after some time of page load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have `javascript` function and that should be called after 3 seconds of complete page load. I know about `setIntervel` but it repeat execution after certain time interval. I want it to execute once. Is it even possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to delay calling of javascript function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5570017/how-to-delay-calling-of-javascript-function)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `setTimeout` instead, as it is called only once after the pause:

```
setTimeout(myFunc, 3000);
```

Answer (score 11):

> The [onload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload) event fires at the end of the document loading process. At this point, all of the objects in the document are in the DOM, and all the images, scripts, links and sub-frames have finished loading, After `onload` you can use `setTimeout` to delay your function execution..

```js
var myFunc = function() {
  alert('After 3 seconds of page load!');
}
window.onload = function() {
  setTimeout(myFunc, 3000);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Using setTimeout:

```
 setTimeout(function(){myfunc()}, 3000);
```

with lambda..

Comment: Thanks, appriciate your help :)

Comment: appreciation is appreciated :)